# Compress image to specific size in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, image-compression

is there any way to compress image based on the image size? I want the output to be 100 to 200 KB for any input image for my Flutter app.

I tried using `flutter_image_compress` but it compresses based on quality not on size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quality == Size

with this you determine your image in uint8list

```
Future<Uint8List> testCompressFile(File file, int quality) async {
    var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile(
      file.absolute.path,
      minWidth: 2300,
      minHeight: 1500,
      quality: 100 - quality,
      rotate: 90,
    );
    print(file.lengthSync());
    print(result.length);
    return result;
  }
```

this will print the size in bytes

```
print(uint8ListImage.lengthInBytes);
```

if the image exceeds 200 kB, you call up the function to the right size (quality)

```
Future<Uint8List> compressImageToLower200kB(File file){
 for( int i = 0 ; i<100 ; i ++ ) {
Uint8List imageCompressed = await testCompressFile(file, i);
  if(imageCompressed.lengthInBytes <200000){
return imageCompressed;
 }
}
```

Comment: This solution although works but is not ideal as this method would take a lot of time to compress one image and won't be helpful if we needed to compress multiple images. User will keep on waiting.

Comment: Determine the compression ratio of flutter_image_compress and you will decrease the time of my algorithm. Bye

Comment: Your solution worked instead of incrementing the for loop by 1 I incremented by factor of 10 and it works and also in less time. Thank you.